# Random BSODs under load

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

When doing things that are CPU/GPU intensive, e.g. games, after a certain period of playing a BSOD will occur. The bug check is different every time but the crash address is always ntoskrnl.exe+14a6f0.

What I have tried:

- Installing the latest version of the GPU driver
- memtest86 (finds nothing)
- Driver Verifier (broke everything and required me to reinstall Windows, which didn't fix the problem)
- Apparently I am missing chipset drivers, I am working to rectify that.

Is there anything else I can do about this?

Comment: Use windbg on the dmp file to analyze the crashes and determine the reason for them

Comment: I have used BlueScreenView on the dmp files and searched the information. That is how I came to the solutions listed in the question.

Comment: BlueScreenView Isn't useful in your case use windbg instead

Comment: As far as I can tell that gives me no more information than BSV does.

Comment: You will have to trust me that , BlueScreenView, is known to blame the wrong driver for the crash

Comment: windbg gives me all the same information that BSV does.

Comment: share the dmp files ,so that I can debug them

Comment: I will upload the dmp files somewhere in a few minutes. I just noticed that, of the five BSODs I've experienced in the last four days (a record low rate), four of them have been related to ntoskrnl.exe. The last three crashed at the same address, ntoskrnl.exe+14a6f0

Comment: Zip with all the last five dmps: http://wikisend.com/download/285968/122816-24203-01.zip

Comment: I posted what I saw from the dumps.

Answer (score 1):

[Checking the dmps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) give no real clue.

1st dump indicated a problem with the Intel LAN driver `e1d65x64.sys` which is from 2015, so a but older:

```
Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\e1d65x64.sys
Image name: e1d65x64.sys
Timestamp:        Thu Aug 13 11:14:29 2015 (55CC5FF5)
```

so update the driver to the last version.

The other dumps show crashes in internal kernel/CPU management functions and graphic operations.

```
05 nt!PpmParkSteerInterrupts
06 nt!PpmCheckPeriodicStart

00 dxgmms2!VidSchiWaitForSchedulerEvents
01 dxgmms2!VidSchiScheduleCommandToRun
02 dxgmms2!VidSchiRun_PriorityTable
03 dxgmms2!VidSchiWorkerThread
04 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
05 nt!KiStartSystemThread
```

I checked the dumps and see that your BIOS/UEFI is very old:

```
BiosVersion = 1204
BiosReleaseDate = 01/19/2016
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoardProduct = Z170 PRO GAMING
```

A few days ago a [new version was posted to improve stability](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170-PRO-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/):

> Z170 PRO GAMING BIOS 3016 Improve system stability

Flash this BIOS/UEFI and look what happens. Also look if the G.Skill F4-2400C15-8GVR RAM modules are tested with your board.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the BIOS, I'll let you know if the problem persists.

Comment: ok, also update the LAN driver. get the driver directly from Intel and not ASUS: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Intel-Ethernet-Adapters-Connections-CD

Comment: As soon as I moved the computer to another building the problems returned. There's been another DirectX related crash.

Comment: do you have AC power issues in your building? an unstable AC power can also cause crashes